# Write all numpy arrays to binary file in a loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np


ds = gdal.Open('image.tif')
# loop through each band
for bi in range(ds.RasterCount):
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(bi + 1)
    # Read this band into a 2D NumPy array
    ar = band.ReadAsArray()
    print('Band %d has type %s'%(bi + 1, ar.dtype))   
    
    ar.astype('uint16').tofile("converted.raw")
```

As a result, I get the converted.raw file, but it only contains data from the last iteration of the for loop. How to make a file that will contain data from all iterations together.

Comment: (re)read the `tofile` docs.  You give it a filename, so it makes a new file each time.  You can give it a `fid`, an already open file.

Answer (score -1):

Use `np.save`

**Ex:**

```
ds = gdal.Open('image.tif')
# loop through each band

with open("converted.raw", "wb") as outfile:
    for bi in range(ds.RasterCount):
        band = ds.GetRasterBand(bi + 1)
        # Read this band into a 2D NumPy array
        ar = band.ReadAsArray()
        print('Band %d has type %s'%(bi + 1, ar.dtype))   
        np.save(outfile, ar.astype('uint16'))
```

Comment: Almost. It is writing 128 bytes numpy header to the file.